# Unresolved overloaded type>[int] for array subscript c++

Tags: c++, arrays, int, overloading

I'm getting the error message 'Unresolved overloaded type>[int] for array subscript' in my flight-booking-system program.

What I'm trying to do is set it so that if [j] is equal to 0,1,2,3... it will display accordingly as A,B,C,D. Until I started doing this my program at least compiled。

```
// Flight Class - Scotia 2
// 
// Contains information on seating (array), space available and return to menu option.


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "passenger.h"
#include "Seat.h"

using namespace std;

/*struct Seat
        {
            int Available;
            std::string fullName;
        };// End of struct*/

class Flight
{

public:
//default constructor
Flight()
{
//initialise all seat numbers
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
    {// assigns seats as 1A, 1B etc...
    seatPlan[i][j].setRow(row);
    if(j==0)
    seatPlan[i][j].setCol('A');
    else if(j==1)
    seatPlan[i][j].setCol('B');
    else if(j==2)
    seatPlan[i][j].setCol('C');
    else if(j==3)
    seatPlan[i][j].setCol('D');
    }
}

Seat seatArray[4][6];

    void seatPlan()
    {
        for (int ROW=0;ROW<4;ROW++)
        {
            for (int COL=0;COL<6;COL++)
                {
                    cout << seatPlan[i][j].getSeatRow();
                }
        }
        // End of for loop
    }// End of seatPlan function

//method which returns true if seat is Available and false otherwise
bool getAvailable(int i, int j)
{
    if(seatArray[i][j].Available == 0)
    return true; //seat available
    else
    return false; //seat occupuied
}

string getName(int i,int j){return seatArray[i][j].fullName;}

void setAvailable(int i, int j, int a){seatArray[i][j].Available = a;}
void setName(int i,int j, string name){seatArray[i][j].fullName = name;}

private:
//variables
int row;
char col;

};// End of Flight class
```

The above is my flight.h file which contains the Flight class. The error message points to my constructor, with the message repeating for all the lines within that contain `seatPlan[i][j].setCol('A');` and so on.

I'll include the 'seat.h' file also, just in case it's relevant.

```
#ifndef SEAT
#define SEAT

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Seat
{

    public:
    //deafult constructor
    Seat(){available = true;}

    //accessor methods
    void setRow(int row){seatRow = row;}
    void setCol(char col){seatCol = col;}

    int getSeatRow(){return seatRow;}
    char getSeatCol(){return seatCol;}

    bool isAvailable(){return available;}
    bool switchAvailable(){
    if(available)
    available = false;
    else
    available = true;
    }

    private:
    bool available;
    int seatRow;
    char seatCol;
};

#endif
```

Comment: In regards to methods (and visibility): since the row and column of a seat is a fairly open piece of information and will most likely not require anything more than a simple get/set of a variable, consider changing the accessibility of `seatRow` and `seatCol` to public.

Comment: That whole if/else if/else if/... mess can quite easily be replaced by `seatArray[i][j].setCol('A' + j)` (as long as `j` will never exceed 26, of course).

Comment: `if(available)
    available = false;
    else
    available = true;` is more simply written as `available = !available;`

Comment: @slyfox: I think you mean as long as `j` will never exceed 25. But the language doesn't guarantee that letters of the Latin alphabet are contiguous; they aren't in EBCDIC, for example.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, you're correct on both counts, thanks. In the absence of specific character set information I assumed ASCII/ISO-8859-1/UTF-8 (where this kind of character tomfoolery is valid) since that's what most people tend to work with nowadays.

Comment: @slyfox: And I don't particularly object to that kind of simplifying assumption as long as it's documented (and preferably tested, as in `assert('Z' - 'A' == 25);`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
seatPlan[i][j].setRow(row);
```

Here is the problem. `seatPlan` is **not** an array. It is the name of the function.

You meant `seatArray`. So it should be:

```
seatArray[i][j].setRow(row);
```

One suggestion: consider using `std::array` as:

```
std::array<std::array<Seat,6>,4> seatArray;
```

instead of

```
Seat seatArray[4][6];
```

Answer (score 1):

`void seatPlan()` is a method and you're treating it as an array. Did you mean `seatArray` instead?

Also

```
if(seatArray[i][j].Available == 0)
return true; //seat available
else
return false; //seat occupuied
```

? Really? Why not just

```
return seatArray[i][j].Available == 0;
```

(assuming you fix the previous error)